# How do i re-install my Ubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, restore

How can I reinstall and reset my Ubuntu just as if I've just installed it for the first time? I'm having issues, for example when I try to update it (I'm using Lubuntu) it does not let me do so and it says it's experiencing an internal error. I'm not sure about what to do:

```
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Fetched 3,641 kB in 12s (284 kB/s)                                             
W: Failed to fetch /openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch /openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: can you add the output of that error to your question just run `sudo apt-get update` via terminal and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/631964/edit) your question to copy paste the output.

Comment: Reinstalling is not going to fix that problem. You have to properly configure  the ppa . http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists

Answer (score 1):

Well I personally do this a few times getting my partition scheme set up, just get a livecd (or .iso) and boot it from a seperate partition(or storage device). This should let you overwrite the filesystem and do the install fresh.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the installation media (DVD, USB or whatever you used) you can use that and click install. But before that you might want to check the disk for errors.
Afterwards you just reinstall Ubuntu using the same way you installed it the first time.
Hope this helps!